# What is wrong with this import export component pattern in React?

Tags: reactjs, storyboard

In my App's React Component library, I have a UIC called Branch which has:

```
Brand.Logo
Brand.WordMark
Brand.WorkMarkLogo
```

Brand.Logo and Brand.WordMark work fine but Brand.WorkMarkLogo outputs the following error in storybook:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Please see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hmfnu

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import and wrap them in curly braces, you're importing a `named export`, not a `default export`.

In your `brand/index.js` file, you have on line 10:

```
 export default Brand;
```

To import a default export in the module, you'll have to omit the curly braces.

So in your `root/index.js` file, change line 3 to

```
import Brand from "./Brand";
```

Alternatively, you can choose to NOT export a default in your `brand/index.js` file, and change put the export in front of your class like this:

```
export class Brand extends React.Component {
  static Logo = Logo;
  static LogoWordMark = LogoWordMark;
}
```

With this method, you can add additional classes like in the same `brand/index.js` file by adding :

```
export class Brand2 extends React.Component {
  static Logo2 = Logo2;
  static LogoWordMark2 = LogoWordMark2;
}
```

Then you'll be able to import both named exports like: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-955rf

Answer (score 4):

In the export default pattern, curly braces are not used.

```js
import  {Brand}  from "./Brand";
```

correct code.

```js
import  Brand  from "./Brand";
```

Only in the 'export' pattern, curly braces are used.

```
export const abc = () => {};
```

```
import {abc} from '...';
```

Comment: index.js  go to line 3

Comment: Thanks tried that still not working... I think it's something to do with how `LogoWordMark` contacts `static Container = styled.div``;` Any idea why that could be a problem?

Comment: He has gave you information actually about the problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3d6iw